# How can I get value of UWSGI_SCRIPT protocol variable?

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am developing web application using Flask. It is deployed with uwsgi. I use Nginx reverse proxy and I am setting UWSGI_SCRIPT variable in config file:

```
uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /my_prefix;
```

I see that requests are handled properly, so Flask is aware of this variable. However, I would like to get its value directly. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

After importing uwsgi it `SCRIPT_NAME` can be found in uwsgi.env. However, only in request context as it is passed from proxy during the request.